# Does DBI (data bus inversion) conserve Entropy?

Tags: encoding, compression, decoding, entropy, information-theory

I have been reading up on DBI on Wikipedia, which references this research paper: [http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4823/handouts/stan-burleson-tvlsi-95.pdf](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecs4823/handouts/stan-burleson-tvlsi-95.pdf)

The paper says:

> While the maximum number of transitions is reduced by half the
> decrease in the average number of transitions is not as good. For an
> 8-bit bus for example the average number of transitions per time-slot
> by using the Bus-invert coding becomes 3.27 (instead of 4), or 0.41
> (instead of 0.5) transitions per bus-line per time-slot.

However this would suggest it reduces the entropy of the 8 bit message, no?
So the entropy of a random 8 bit message is 8 (duh). Add a DBI bit which shifts the probability distribution to the left, but it (I thought) wouldn't reduce the area under the curve. You should still be left with a minimum of 8 bits of entropy, but spread over 9 bits. But they claim the average is now 0.41, instead of 0.5, which suggests the entropy is now -log( (0.59)^9) = ~6.85. I would have assumed the average would (at best) become 0.46 (-log(0.54 ^9) = ~8).

Am I misunderstanding something?